# Joining the same table multiple times in a query

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has multiple user ID columns (uidA, uidB, uidC, etc), which are linked to a user table.  I understand you can join the same table multiple times, but I'm curious if this is the most efficient way of writing my query by joining the same table three times?

```
SELECT
    userA.`username`,
    userB.`username`,
    userC.`username`,
    `someTable`.`someValue`,
    `someTable`.`timestamp`
FROM `someTable`
INNER JOIN `users` userA ON userA.`id` = `someTable`.`uidA`
INNER JOIN `users` userB ON userB.`id` = `someTable`.`uidB`
INNER JOIN `users` userC ON userC.`id` = `someTable`.`uidC`
WHERE `someTable`.`someValue` = ?
```

Comment: There MIGHT be a more efficient way, but it wouldn't nearly be as straightforward. It would involve your `JOIN` condition `OR`ing those separate conditions together, and then some sort of `GROUP BY` and three `GROUP_CONCAT(IF(...))`s. It would be kind of convoluted, and probably slower in 99% of cases.

Comment: Ah okay.  I'll just stick with this then.  Thanks @Uueerdo

Comment: @Drew There not always has to be scalability. Imagine e.g. chat. This is pretty natural to store both sender and recipient ID referring to the users table. Then you retrieve message info using the query like the one OP posted.

Comment: ok, in chat I have a chat id #. There are 2 or more people chatting under that chat id # unless someone is talking to themselves. sequenced by autoincrement or datetime. not more than one user id regardless

Comment: @Drew Nobody said you should always store related user ids in the same raw. I was merely commenting on your point (that this is *unconditionally* bad way).

Comment: @Drew in my code, I have an order.  That order can have different stages (who entered it, who prepared it, who delivered it.)  For each stage, I have a column of when it was completed and by who.  Is this not a good way to structure it?  I can lookup on any of the three uid columns (if I want to see who completed a certain step) and it seems to scale well.

Comment: ok, 2 things to look out for. **1)** second and third are null so good luck with the inner join. This would not be a problem with another structured approach. **2)** What happens when you need steps 4 and 5. As if problem 1 isnt bad enough (true you could change your join strategy). Food for thought.

Comment: Well left join is probably what I should have put.  How would I structure it to keep track of the progress of an order?  Generally, things are searched by the status (someValue in my example) of that order.  And dependent on the status, uidA...C are checked.

Comment: if it is not terribly broken I would not fix it. I would cross that bridge when you come to it or foreseeable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the way to join same table multiple times.

Comment: this is a horrible way you mean !

Comment: @Drew No i do not. Please do not attribute your thoughts to others. For what the OP wanted (using different records from the same table multiple times) his is a straightforward and efficient way.